# simple maths with jQuery

Tags: jquery, math

I need to add some items together using jquery, how would i go about doing this?

I have.

- 1 item @ £1.00
- 1 Shipping @ £4.05

I need to basically add 1 x 1.00. Then add that total to the shipping so I can display the grand total.

Comment: You appear to have fundamentally misunderstood what jQuery is and its relationship with JavaScript...

Comment: We need to see what your code looks like. Your markup and any script you may be using in relation to this data.

Comment: We need your html to do this.

Comment: `var total = (1 * 1.00) + 4.05;`  Without seeing your HTML/JavaScript code, that's all I can do.

Comment: 4 pounds shipping on a 1 pound item, what a rip-off (just kidding) :-P

Comment: @Rocket lol I'd be pissed if it were not test data lol only have to set it at that otherwise amazon would charge me the full amount for an item as they make you use you OWN credit/debit card!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple in JS

```
 var answer = 1*1
```

jQuery isn't necessary, but might be to output your answer

```
$('.price').html("£"+answer);
```

Comment: works thanks, i thought it was that simple :) How do i deal with it, if the price is stored as a decimal?

Comment: Sorry, would have responded sooner but had a baby instead!! What do you mean? Do you mean you want to force the number to have two decimal places (pence) ?

Comment: All sorted now :) congrats on the little one, hope it all went well and mother and baby are doing well.